# Unusual ./configure error when building GDAL 2.0.0 from source

Tags: configure, gdal

Ubuntu 15.04 does not distribute packages for GDAL 2.0.0 yet so I'm attempting a source build, with reference to the [official instructions](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildingOnUnix)

```
wget http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/2.0.0/gdal-2.0.0.tar.gz
tar xzf gdal-2.0.0.tar.gz
cd gdal-2.0.0
./configure
```

Output (last few lines)

```
configure: checking whether we should include rasdaman support...
        rasdaman support not requested.
checking whether we should include Armadillo support... no
configure: creating ./config.status
./config.status: line 2276: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

- I've also tried the nightly SVN snapshot, which also fails to configure.,
- config.status is exactly 2276 lines long, so I'm guessing mismatched quotes, but able to spot the error in such a large machine generated file.
- I've seen other questions suggesting this might be a DOS vs UNIX linefeed issue. So I can dos2unix on the config.status file...

dos2unix / file

```
$ file config.status 
config.status: Bourne-Again shell script executable (binary data)

$ dos2unix config.status 
dos2unix: Binary symbol 0x00 found at line 317
dos2unix: Skipping binary file config.status
```

The content of config.status from line 314

```
    while :; do
      case $as_dir in #(                                                                                                                                    
      *\'*) as_qdir=`$as_echo "$as_dir" | sed "s/'/'\\\\\\\\''/g"`;; #'(                                                                                    
      *) as_qdir=$as_d^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^\
@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@\
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^\
@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@\
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^\
@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@\
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^\
@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@\
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^\
@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@\
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^\
@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@\
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^\
@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@\
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^\
@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@\
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^\
@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@\
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@# Save the log message, to keep $0 and so on meaningful, and to
# report actual input values of CONFIG_FILES etc. instead of their                                                                                          
# values after options handling.    
ac_log="                                                                                                                                                    
This file was extended by $as_me, which was                                                                                                                 
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was                                                                                                

  CONFIG_FILES    = $CONFIG_FILES                                                                                                                           
  CONFIG_HEADERS  = $CONFIG_HEADERS                                                                                                                         
  CONFIG_LINKS    = $CONFIG_LINKS                                                                                                                           
  CONFIG_COMMANDS = $CONFIG_COMMANDS                                                                                                                        
  $ $0 $@                                                                                                                                                   

on `(hostname || uname -n) 2>/dev/null | sed 1q`                                                                                                            
"
```

Questions.

- How is configure able to generate corrupt output, is it something relating to my environment?
- Are the ^@ characters a normal Bash thing, or cause of the problem?

Comment: config.status should be a POSIX shell script text executable, so something happened early on in the configuration. It could be a missing package or a bug. If you could, submit [a bug report](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/) attaching `config.log` and `config.status`. You may need [a userid](http://www.osgeo.org/osgeo_userid).

Comment: @MikeT Thanks for the suggestion, in the process of recreating the problem to raise a ticket I discovered the issue... I was using VM shared folders which seems to have side effect of breaking ./configure in this weird way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

./configure seems sensitive to the source being in a sub-directory inside a VM shared folder (vmhgfs)

```
.host:/adam    500105212 141512588 358592624  29% /mnt/adam
```

- When in /mnt/adam/gdal-2.0.0 ./configure works correctly
- When in ~/adam/gdal/gdal-2.0.0 ./configure works correctly
- However in /mnt/adam/gdal/gdal-2.0.0  ./configure fails with error in question.

I can only assume this is some Unix permissions issue etc.